# Large pdf is not geting printed in IE 11 using PDFJS

Tags: javascript, viewer, pdf.js

If I try to print a Large Pdf in IE 11, the printed output doesn't contain all the pages. In a few page cross icons are coming. I have reduced the resolution of the file at the time of printing but still, I am not able to Print it properly. Can someone point to me what I can do to solve this issue? Thanks

My Viewer Code for printing

```
function renderPage(activeServiceOnEntry, pdfDocument, pageNumber, size) {
    var scratchCanvas = activeService.scratchCanvas;
    var PRINT_RESOLUTION = _app_options.AppOptions.get('printResolution') || 150;
    var PRINT_UNITS = PRINT_RESOLUTION / 72.0;
    scratchCanvas.width = Math.floor(size.width * PRINT_UNITS);
    scratchCanvas.height = Math.floor(size.height * PRINT_UNITS);
    var width = Math.floor(size.width * _ui_utils.CSS_UNITS) + 'px';
    var height = Math.floor(size.height * _ui_utils.CSS_UNITS) + 'px';
    var ctx = scratchCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, scratchCanvas.width, scratchCanvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    return pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (pdfPage) {
      var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: ctx,
        transform: [PRINT_UNITS, 0, 0, PRINT_UNITS, 0, 0],
        viewport: pdfPage.getViewport({
          scale: 1,
          rotation: size.rotation
        }),
        intent: 'print'
      };
      return pdfPage.render(renderContext).promise;
    }).then(function () {
      return {
        width: width,
        height: height
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does anything appear in the console on IE?  Also are you generating this client side / or server side.?

Comment: Nothing is appearing in console.

Comment: Pdf is generated at server side. The printing logic is in client side